# Max Mysql Connection Per Load

Tags: mysql, performance

i am running a wordpress website with on VULTR VPS 1GB RAM SSD,
my website has 20000+ posts and now its even slow on 4GB RAM VPS i think this is just for max mysql load right? im just noob in programming, please figure this out for me , how to load my website faster with this 20000+ posts or what to configure in the server ?

Comment: A slow system may be caused by a lot of reasons. The information you provided is not enough to earnestly try a diagnose. You will have to try and measure (more memory, e.g.). Do you load all these posts on startup? Maybe you should think about pagination.

Comment: posts shows on homepage by NEW to OLD , i have seen that the problem is not for memory in phpsysinfo because the memory load is normal. any special configuration in PHP.ini maybe needed [i think] maybe the website loads slowly for MYSQL connection , i just want to know the possible reasons so that i can figure out this problem

Comment: Hire a professional to help you optimize your site, you gave 0.0001% of required info to identify the bottleneck, and you have substantial lack of knowledge to perform optimization on your own. Getting info out of you would probably span in days. If you want to save time and have your site up and running without wasting too much time (time = money), just google someone in your vicinity that deals with these problems and pay them to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You provided very little info so it's impossible to diagnose the problem. 
First you should monitor the system: CPU, memory, I/O and check if any of these are close to the limits. 
Second you should monitor the database: have you access to the DB server? have you access to any monitoring facilities? 
If the performance decreased when the post increased it's possible that the problem is the DB but you must understand what: a missing index? an outdated statistic?

Anyway nothing can be said without a proper monitoring

Answer (score 0):

1GB RAM -- that is *tiny* by today's standards.

Check for swapping.  That is a killer for MySQL.

Which "Engine" are your tables?  (Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for a typical table.)

If ENGINE=MyISAM, look in my.cnf for key_buffer_size; it should be something like 50M.  (400M for 4GB of RAM)

If ENGINE=InnoDB, look in my.cnf for innodb_buffer_pool_size; it should be something like 150M (1200M for 4GB of RAM) and key_buffer_size should be about 10M.

If your settings are significantly smaller than those, that is likely to be the problem.  To double check the settings, do (from phpmyadmin, mysql commandline tool, or wherever):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';
```